# What do we know about the Mandalorian's Way?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-mandalorian, mandalorian

Watching Disney's **The Mandalorian**, we got to know that *Mandalorian isn't a race. It's a Creed.* as uttered by Cara Dune and Din Djarin, also we heard several times Djarin and other Mandalorians on the show say: *This is The Way* (presumably of the Mandalore). What do we know about this Way and creed, whether Canon or Legends? Is it like the Jedi books or some sort of unwritten code of honor and conduct amongst Mandalorians?

Comment: This is a potentially very broad question. Could you specify? Are you asking what the creed contains?

Comment: It is implied by the conversation when he meets Bo-Katan that Din was raised by a group  who don't follow the same "way" as the rest of the people who consider themselves Mandalorian. I doubt there will be much canon information on this available (at least until the series is fleshed out with some supplementary material), but I would strongly suspect that Favreau and Filoni would have based it on what there is in Legends based on Mandalore from the time of the Old Republic.

Comment: You should watch all the Mandalorian Clone Wars and Rebels episodes to get an idea.

Comment: @sf02 Eh, that doesn't really help. You'll learn that Bo-Katan was in fact part of Death Watch, but thought nothing of taking her helmet off. So we know Mando was brought up in some cult even more extreme than them that was never seen in Clone Wars/Rebels (that I recall).

Comment: @Harabeck You're right that it might not help for Djarin's specific creed, but it will demonstrate that Mandalorian creeds/groups can be completely opposite and different from each other, so basically anything goes.

Answer (score 7):

Not a whole lot.  We know:

That it's a fundamentalist interpretation of an ancient creed (the Way of the Mandalore) that isn't widely practiced by mainstream Mandalorian culture anymore.

A central tenet is the wearing of the helmet and not removing it in front of anyone.  Having removed it, you're not supposed to put it back on anymore as you're no longer a Mandalorian.

The priest role is played by an "Armorer" who both makes/upgrades armor and weapons as well as interprets the "Way," whatever it may be at that time.

Word and agreements are important.  Having entered into an agreement and given one's word, a Mandalorian is obligated to fulfill the terms and then never speak of it again.  This is followed by Boba Fett, but notably not by Bo Katan.

Family and Clans are important.  The pre-Empire leadership seems to be a parliamentary monarchy.

There is a custom of taking on orphans or parents separated from their families.  Having done so, the Mandalorians either raise them as one of their own or returns them to their own culture, preferably their families.

Foundlings are both "Found" and can apparently Found a new clan if they face a trial and are judged worthy by an Armorer.  A clan has a signet forged by an Armorer on their shoulder.

Armor and the metal beskar is considered sacred and is passed down through generations.

That's about it so far.

Answer (score 3):

"The Way" is referring to the Mandalorian Creed which, according to the traditions of Mandalore, all Mandalorians must swear when they are a certain (undetermined) age, as a right of passage. We know that clans are an important part of the Way of the Mandalore, and that young Mandalorians forge their armor with their family, supposedly after they swear the creed. (I will insert the direct quote when I can find it) The Mandalorian Creed (also known to Mandalorians as resol'nare) is as follows:

[image: The Mandalorian Creed, or resol'nare]

There is more about the Way of the Mandalore in Star Wars canon, and I will add more information when I can access it.

Comment: Where are you referencing the The Mandalorian Creed from?

Comment: Information about resol'nare can be found on the official Wookieepedia page, but the information I have provided (for now) is from my own knowledge of the Star Wars canon. As I mentioned in my answer, I will provide direct quotes when I can access them. here is a link to the Wookieepedia page: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Resol%27nare